# Rails - Override primary key on has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations, basically I want to link via userid and not the id of the object.

`class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_profile, :primary_key => 'userid', :foreign_key => 'twitter_userid'`

`class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tweet, :foreign_key => 'userid'`

However the following spec fails as twitter_userid is reset to the id of the object

`it "should have the user's twitter id set on their user profile" do
   t = Tweet.new(:twitter_id => 1,
                  :status => 'Tester', 
                  :userid => 'personA',
                  :user_profile => UserProfile.new(:twitter_userid => 'personA', :avatar => 'abc'))
   t.save!
    t.user_profile.twitter_userid.should == 'personA'
 end`

should have the user's twitter id set on their user profile

```
expected: "personA",
    got: 216 (using ==)
```

However, the following does pass:

```
 it "should return the correct avatar after being saved" do
   t = Tweet.new(:twitter_id => 1,
                  :status => 'Tester', 
                  :userid => 'personA', 
                  :user_profile => UserProfile.new(:twitter_userid => 'personA', :avatar => 'abc'))
   t.save!

   t.user_profile.avatar.should == 'abc'
 end
```

How can I force it to use userid and not id?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: is 'personA' going into your db?

Comment: This passes, so yes it is: 
<pre>
 it "should save" do
   t = Tweet.new(:twitter_id => 1,
                  :status => 'Tester', 
                  :userid => 'personA',         
                  :user_profile => UserProfile.new(:twitter_userid => 'personA', :avatar => 'abc'))
   t.save!
   
   t.userid.should == 'personA'
   t.new_record?.should == false
   t.valid?.should == true
   t.user_profile.new_record?.should == false
   t.user_profile.valid?.should == true
 end
</pre>

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use userid as the foreign key?  Why not just use the primary key of the associated field.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here. I think you have switched the :has_one and :belongs_to declarations.

The `:belongs_to` comes in the model that has the foreign-key.
The `:has_one` comes in the model that is referred to (if it is only one, otherwise if many rows :belong_to the same, it is a has_many of course). For more info read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

First, you will need to specify (overrule) the primary key of the model. Here i am assuming a user can have many tweets instead of just one (otherwise replace by `:has_one`).

```
class UserProfile
  set_primary_key :userid
  has_many :tweets 
end
```

then you need to adjust your `:has_one` declaration:

```
class Tweet
  belongs_to :user_profile, :foreign_key => :userid
end
```

Then, secondly, once your relations are setup correctly, there is no need to assign both `:user_profile` or `:userid` at creation time. Either you create a new `UserProfile` and the foreign-keys will automatically by correct, or you assign an `userid` of an existing profile.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
cite@antiope:/tmp/foo$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
>> t = Tweet.new(:twitter_id => 1,
?>                   :status => 'Tester', 
?>                   :userid => 'personA',
?>                   :user_profile => UserProfile.new(:twitter_userid => 'personA', :avatar => 'abc'))
=> #<Tweet id: nil, twitter_id: 1, status: "Tester", userid: "personA", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> Tweet.set_primary_key :userid
=> nil
>> t.save
  Tweet Create (0.4ms)   INSERT INTO "tweets" ("created_at", "updated_at", "userid", "twitter_id", "status") VALUES('2009-09-10 20:19:36', '2009-09-10 20:19:36', 'personA', 1, 'Tester')
  UserProfile Create (0.1ms)   INSERT INTO "user_profiles" ("twitter_userid", "created_at", "updated_at", "avatar") VALUES('personA', '2009-09-10 20:19:36', '2009-09-10 20:19:36', 'abc')
=> true
>> Tweet.set_primary_key :id
=> nil
```

Modfiying the model a split second before saving it  might be an acceptable solution if you only have to redefine the primary key in one place (I didn't test if modifying the `Tweet` class like that affected only the current controller or **all** actions). Still, it's only what I consider to be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key on your db is not called id then you want to do something like this:

```
class Tweet < AR:B
  set_primary_key "userid" 
end
```

However, I'm not sure I totally understand the question.  Is there a reason you want to step outside of the rails conventions?

Comment: thanks, but my ID is id. Yet, for this association I want to use a different column

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the most practical way.  I don't think it is possible in Rails otherwise:
http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/